# How can I politely ask to discuss compensation before the interview process without sounding arrogant?

Tags: interviewing, salary

I have over 14 years of experience in game development and I receive an average 2 unsolicited interview requests on LinkedIn per week. One of those seemed like a good opportunity and after three days of interviewing and taking tests they proposed me a position with a salary that was about 50% of what I'm currently making and they didn't negotiate, which of course I refused.

Those interviews are time-demanding and tiresome and I don't want to go through those again only to find out in the end they can't afford me. At the same time, I don't want them to think the only thing that matters for me is the money.

Answer (score 2):

> Those interviews are time-demanding and tiresome and I don't want to
>   go through those again only to find out in the end they can't afford
>   me. At the same time, I don't want them to think the only thing that
>   matters for me is the money.

State your minimum salary right off the gate. Something along the lines "The opportunity looks great, just FYI the minimum salary I would consider is XYZ, is that alright?". Bringing this up is not going to make you sound arrogant, money is very important factor of a job offer, and making sure you are in the same ballpark is important for everyone involved, nor does it mean that you only care about money.

It's also important to understand that this is your minimum consideration amount, it doesn't mean that you will accept offer at this amount, but merely that you do not entertain anything below it.